# Remove reflection of stock image

Tags: glass, reflection

Trying to texture an eye in Blender 2.8, but when I apply the glass node I get a reflection of the scenic countryside. Help.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're using the workbench render engine. There isn't anything wrong with it at all. It's just that workbench uses a built-in HDRI as well as EEVEE to render your scene. If you switch over to cycles or EEVEE, it will work as you weould expect.

Comment: Also, depending on various settings, transparency effects may be limited in Eevee/workbench.